# Wordpress custom post type page

Tags: wordpress

When creating a custom post type and fill it with some posts wordpress generates a page for that custom post type.

But I want to be able to add content to that page so I create a regular page and choose a template where I manually call the custom post type posts and loop them out. And now I can just add content in the wysiwyg editor. But this causes a conflict between these two pages, especially if the CPT has the same name as the page.

And now the question: Is there a way to always show the page where I have chosen the template for the CPT to always show? Even when someone try's to manually enter the url for the CPT generated page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood from your question. You have custom post type. Then you created a page-template, that loops through your custom post types and output them. Now when you create a new page and assign it the page-template you have created you run into problems, if it has the same name as the custom post type.

Solution: I think what you need to do is change the custom-page slug from the admin menu. Then you would be able to directly reference it by the URL.